# Find and FindNext

Tags: excel, vba

### I’m new to VBA and need some help. After days of searching on internet and experimenting with code, I can't get it to work.

@brettdj, @ryguy7272
Thanks alot. Both your codes works perfectly, but I understand now I have not explained my problem correctly. You don't need to write full code, just show how to continue with second dynamic range. So if you bear with me, here is the full explanation:

I have eight dynamic ranges in six columns in sheet1 (48 ranges in total), 
to be copied to 48 static cells in sheet2.

For dynamic ranges: Col"A" have text as start and end value. The other 5 columns have text as start values and empty cell as end values.

Sheet1, col"A", find first occ. of (textstring) "ABC".

Sheet1, col"A", find first occ. of (textstring) "DEF*" ("*" means any character), after "ABC".

This dynamic range shall be copied to Sheet2, "A2"

Sheet1, col"B", find first occ. of (textstring) "GHI"

Sheet1, col"B", find first occ. of (textstring) "" (empty cell) after "GHI"

This dynamic range shall be copied to Sheet2, "C2"

etc

etc.

Below you can read code I have used so far, to do it by columns but I'm stuck when I shall start over at Col"A", and next occ. of "ABC", dynamicly to next occ. of "DEF*.

I.E.:

Sheet1, col"A", find second occ. of "ABC"

Sheet1, col"A", find second occ. of "DEF*", after "ABC"

This dynamic range shall be copied to Sheet2, "A22"

Sheet1, col"B", find second occ. of "GHI"

Sheet1, col"B", find second occ. of "" (empty cell) after "GHI"

This dynamic range shall be copied to Sheet2, "C22"

etc etc. (se code below)

Sheet1: rows= dynamic. Columns: 1,2,3,4,5,9

Sheet2: 8 static rows= 2,22,42,62,82,102,122,142. Columns: 1,3,6,7,9,18

```
Sub Module1()
Dim foundA As Range, _
    foundB As Range
Dim newSht As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo Terminate

With Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)
    Set foundA = .Find("ABC")
    Set foundB = .Find("DEF*", After:=foundA, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
End With
    Range(foundA(2), foundB(0)).Copy
    Set newSht = Sheets("Sheet2")
    newSht.Range("A2").PasteSpecial

With Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(2)
    Set foundA = .Find("GHI")
    Set foundB = .Find("", After:=foundA, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
End With
    Range(foundA(2), foundB(0)).Copy
    Set newSht = Sheets("Sheet2")
    newSht.Range("C2").PasteSpecial

With Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(3)
    Set foundA = .Find("JKL")
    Set foundB = .Find("", After:=foundA, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
End With
    Range(foundA(2), foundB(0)).Copy
    Set newSht = Sheets("Sheet2")
    newSht.Range("F2").PasteSpecial


With Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(4)
    Set foundA = .Find("MNO")
    Set foundB = .Find("", After:=foundA, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
End With
    Range(foundA(2), foundB(0)).Copy
    Set newSht = Sheets("Sheet2")
    newSht.Range("G2").PasteSpecial


With Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(5)
    Set foundA = .Find("PQR")
    Set foundB = .Find("", After:=foundA, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
End With
    Range(foundA(2), foundB(0)).Copy
    Set newSht = Sheets("Sheet2")
    newSht.Range("I2").PasteSpecial


With Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(9)
    Set foundA = .Find("STU")
    Set foundB = .Find("", After:=foundA, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
End With
    Range(foundA(2), foundB(0)).Copy
    Set newSht = Sheets("Sheet2")
    newSht.Range("R2").PasteSpecial


Exit Sub
Terminate:
MsgBox "Error in Code"
End

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I hope it's understandable. If not please ask for clarification.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: We can't get your code to work either. :( But if you post what you've got maybe we can make it work together. :)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

Comment: @Tim, I'm sorry my text isn't understandable. Pls check my edit.

Comment: I understood your question, but SO isn't a code writing service. SO is for help debugging your existing code. You didn't provide any code, so no one is going to be able to help you debug it. Try recording a macro where you find "ABC", then integrate a loop. We'll help you if you run into snags.

Comment: @Tim, Ooops! Sorry, me bad. Didn't know. Ok, I'll try out something.

Comment: @brettdj, Thanks for answer. Please see my update

Comment: @ryguy7272,  Thanks for answer. Please see my update

Comment: @Tim, Please see my update. Is that something you can work with?

Comment: You've changed your question substantially. I'm not going to recraft a new answer for this. cheers

Comment: @brettdj, I understand. Thanks anyway for your code, I had use for that one too. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question you can use `Find` and `Findnext` as so:

```
Sub Update()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim StrIn As String
Dim strAdd As String
Dim lngCnt As Long

StrIn = "ABC"
With Worksheets(1).Columns(1)
        Set rng1 = .Find(StrIn, .Cells(Rows.Count, "A"), xlValues, xlWhole, xlNext)
        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        strAdd = rng1.Address
        Set rng2 = rng1
        Do
            Set rng1 = .FindNext(rng1)
        Set rng2 = Union(rng2, rng1)
        Loop While Not rng1 Is Nothing And rng1.Address <> strAdd
    End If
End With

If rng2 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

For Each rng3 In rng2
lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
rng3 = "code " & lngCnt
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
Sub Insert()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1")
    While rng.Value <> ""
        If rng.Value = "ABC" Then
            rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
        End If
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
    Wend
End Sub
```